# Using custom iOS 7 transition with subclassed UINavigationController occasionally results in black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I am subclassing a `UINavigationController` to serve as the main root controller of my application.  The purpose of the view controller is to present a custom splash screen that allows for a swipe action from (right to left) to enter the main application.  The custom transition fades the splash view during the swipe and reveals the main application underneath (a `UITabBarController`).  Most of my code is following the objc.io article on custom view controller transitions in iOS7: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html.

Everything seems to work as expected.  However, very rarely, I am getting reports of a black screen appearing once the splash screen disappears, instead of the main screen.  I have been unable to reproduce the behavior.   Here is the code:

First, setting up the main root view controller in the custom app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.rootViewController = [[CustomRootViewController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:nil toolbarClass:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Important portions from `CustomRootViewController` (note I'm hiding the navigation bar):

```
- (instancetype) initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass
{
    self = [super initWithNavigationBarClass:navigationBarClass toolbarClass:toolbarClass];
    if (self) {
        self.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self;

    // This is the main UI for the app
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    CustomTabBarControllerViewController *mainViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.mainViewController = mainViewController;

    UIStoryboard *splashStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Splash" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    SplashViewController *splashViewController = [splashStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.splashViewController = splashViewController;

    // Initialize the navigation controller to have the main app sitting under the splash screen
    self.viewControllers = @[self.mainViewController, self.splashViewController];
}

// In the public interface, called from the Splash screen when the user can perform the action
- (void)allowSwipeToDismiss
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop) {
        return [[CustomRootViewControllerAnimator alloc ] init];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                         interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController
{
    return self.interactiveController;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Only enable swiping when on the Swipe To Enter screen
    // After we are in the main app, we don't want this gesture recognizer interfering with the rest of the app
    if (self.topViewController == self.splashViewController) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.interactiveController = [[UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition alloc] init];
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat viewWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat percentDone = -translation.x / viewWidth;
        [self.interactiveController updateInteractiveTransition:percentDone];
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (self.interactiveController.percentComplete < 0.5) {
            [self.interactiveController cancelInteractiveTransition];
        } else {
            [self.interactiveController finishInteractiveTransition];
        }
        self.interactiveController = nil;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the `CustomRootViewControllerAnimator` being returned by my custom UINavigationController:

```
@implementation CustomRootViewControllerAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    [[transitionContext containerView] insertSubview:toViewController.view
                                        belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-screenWidth, 0);
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to replicate the problem, but only in iOS 7.0.  By starting the interactive transition, then canceling it, I was able to get the black screen on the next start of the transition.  In the completion block, I needed to set the alpha value of the fromViewController back to 1.  Again, this is only necessary in iOS 7.0.  It does not happen in 7.1.